# Parsing dates using localtimezone to date object in javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone, timezone-offset, date-parsing

I want to parse a date into a javascript date object. I am using the following

```
new Date(Date.parse('2012-08-01'))
```

The problem is my input date can be in multiple formats and parsing it should always give me the date object with the date as

*2012-08-01 00:00:00*

in local timezone.

What are possible options in javascript without using any third party libraries ?

I have a possible solution. But my concern is should i be worried that this will not work in certain android/iphone/kindle/surface native browsers?

```
var timezone = new Date().toString().match(/([A-Z]+[\+-][0-9]+)/)[1];
var dateObject = new Date(Date.parse('2012-08-01 '+timezone));
```

Comment: when you say no 3rd party libraries, are you talking about JS framework agnosticism? (ie no jQuery/mooTools etc.) or not even working with vanilla JS libraries?

Comment: specifically mooTools...I use Jquery in my app, but dont want to add more dependencies. native javascript is ok. What are you referring to when u say vanialla JS libraries?

Comment: Jacob Wright created this JS version of PHP's date format abilities that just uses plain JS (aka vanilla JS) http://jacwright.com/projects/javascript/date_format/  this might be a step in the right direction in terms of formatting and updating for local timezone, couple that with something like `var tz = -(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60); // user timezone offset returned in sec` and you should be pretty sorted

Answer (score 1):

Replace the dashes with forward slashes and it will use the local time.  Be sure to use `yyyy/mm/dd` ordering if you want it to work everywhere.

You also do not need to explicitly call `Date.parse`.  The `Date` constructor will do that when you pass a string.

```
new Date('2012/08/01')  // local
new Date('2012-08-01')  // UTC
```

Yes, JavaScript is weird.