# Convert UTC to standard date time format using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, utc

How can I convert a UTC time into proper date - time format using Javascript?

This is what I want to do

```
var d = new Date("2014-01-01");
var new_d = d.toUTC(); // 1388534400000
var old_d = function(new_d){
    // return "2014-01-01" // how can i get this? 
}
```

Now How, can i get orignal date - 2014-01-01 from 1388534400000?

****Also, Please note that when i do this --- new Date(1388534400000); it gives date 1 day less. 
That is, instead of giving *Jan 01 2014*, it gives *Dec 31 2013*. But, I want Jan 01 2014.****

Is there any method to do the opposite of toUTC() method?

// _________ For those whose toUTC() doesnt work

*"toUTC" method works in console of my chrome
See screen shot below*

[image]

Comment: @janaspage: How can I fix that? I do not want that time to get off by hours or even minutes. Can I achieve that?

Comment: Please show us the `.toUTC()` function you use, because it is that function that does it!

Comment: *sigh* - this is about the billionth question of this sort.  The simple answer is to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  The harder answer is that hyphens trigger the date object to use UTC.  For example, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24070550/634824) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18774293/634824).

Comment: @MattJohnson - That is not the issue here.

Comment: `toUTC` is nonstandard though. You must have it declared in some script that is loaded, or using some non-standard version of chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a string containing hyphens to the `Date` constructor, it will treat that as UTC.  And if you don't pass a time, it will consider it to be midnight.  If you are in a time zone that is behind UTC (such as in most of the Americas), you will see the wrong local time conversion.

Here's a screenshot of my chrome dev console, so you can see what I mean

[image: screenshot]

If I pass slashes instead:

[image: screenshot]

Consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) - which will accept a format parameter that will help you avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```
new Date(new_d);
```

Comment: it returns this - Tue Dec 31 2013 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST) and I want 2014-01-01. Also, I dont know why it returns this date ---Dec 31 2013 , instead of this date --- Jan 1 2014

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the way you **instantiate the Date**.
Javascript interpretes the hyphens as an utc date, and slashes as local dates.

Giving the results that mark Explains.

```
var utcDate = new Date('2014-01-01') // returns a UTC date
var localDate = new Date('2014/01/01'); // Returns local date
```

But to translate a date back to your starting point string, you can do the following.

```
function toDateString(utcMillis){
    var date = new Date(utcMillis);
    d = date.getDate();
    m = date.getMonth() +1;
    y = date.getFullYear();
    return y + '-' + addLeadingZero(m, 2) + '-' + addLeadingZero(d,2);
}

function addLeadingZero(n, length){
   n = n+'';
   if(n.length<length)
      return addLeadingZero('0'+n, length--);
   else
      return n;
}
```

---

### If you find yourself with a UTC date, you can still do this:

```
function toUTCDateString(utcMillis){
    var date = new Date(utcMillis);
    d = date.getUTCDate();
    m = date.getUTCMonth() +1;
    y = date.getUTCFullYear();
    return y + '-' + addLeadingZero(m, 2) + '-' + addLeadingZero(d,2);
}
```

[**To play around with it, and see it for yourself, see this Fiddle:**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qv22X/)

Comment: This is great. However, I dont know why it returns 1 day less because new Date("2014-01-01").toUTC() gives 1388534400000. So toUTCDate(1388534400000) should give back 2014-01-01. instead it gives one day less. Not sure why that's happening?

Comment: Your function `.toUTC()` doesn't exist in the standard. So I can't tell you why your results differ.

Make a fiddle show casing your problem.

Comment: However, new Date("2012-01-01") gives Sat Dec 31 2011 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST). So, it is not toUTC method but Date itself add some regional offset i guess

Comment: Nope it's your `toUTC()` that is breaking it.

Comment: Nope, it is not. I tested